# CSS white bite and oval form in spinner

Tags: css

I'm playing making my own UI library, I'm working on an Input component who is able to add components (like an icon or spinner) to the sides and I have [this strange spinner bug](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-breeze-s80uy). There are two problems that are explained in the code.

If I uncheck & check the `width` attr from dev tools, the "white bite" fixes.

PD: The example is written in a react project because I want to add behaviour later, but now it's just a simple css problem.

EDIT: This is the image of the oval when you remove the "dummy-wrapper" div.

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: teal;
  padding: 0.4em 0.5em;
  background: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0em 0.4em;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Poppins;
  color: black;
  /* TODO: make themeable */
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.14px;
}

.spinner {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.2rem solid rgba(151, 159, 208, 0.3);
  border-top-color: inherit;
  animation: 1s spin infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <label>X</label>
      <input
        placeholder="this is a placeholder......"
        value="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
      />
      <!--{/* Problem 1: Without the dummy-wrapper the circle becomes an oval. */}
      {/* Problem 2: The circle has a small white bite. */}-->
      <div class="dummy-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Guidelines say you should provide the code here on SO

Comment: the white seems to be only a visual effect , slow it down, stop the rotation, use other colors or add a background color to find out.

Comment: Hello David, 
`Problem 1: Without the dummy-wrapper the circle becomes an oval.?`
please use  `min-width: 15px; min-height: 15px;` instead of  `width: 15px; height: 15px;` to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a fixed `px` border width, I guess it might be the border width `0.2rem` => `3.1875px` chrome view resolution problem.

`border: 3px solid rgba(151, 159, 208, 0.3);`

Comment: OMG `px` did the trick, it seems that the browser translate `rem` to `px` and the decimals are not very well rendered.

Comment: can you help me with `Problem 1: Without the dummy-wrapper the circle becomes an oval.`?

Comment: @DavidRearte Do you mean no borders?

Comment: no, I mean if you remove the "dummy-wrapper" div from the HTML, the circle becomse an oval. I added an image to the post

Comment: @DavidRearte because `flex`,  the width is affected by 'flex'

Comment: @DavidRearte try add`flex-shrink: 0;` To in the `.spinner`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem there ... ?

```css
.spinner {
  --spinSz        : 32px;  /* spinner size */
  box-sizing      : border-box;
  display         : inline-block;
  flex-shrink     : 0;
  width           : var(--spinSz);
  height          : var(--spinSz);
  border-radius   : 50%;
  border          : calc(var(--spinSz)/10) solid #1a31c54d;
  border-top-color: #830b2f;
  animation       : 1s spin infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<b class="spinner"></b>
```

Comment: the problem is not the spinner itself, is when it's inside the container. Thanks anyway for the `css var` tip. EDIT: the problem was that I was using `rem` as border unit size and px as width and height, using the same unit for both did the trick.

Comment: can you help me with `Problem 1: Without the dummy-wrapper the circle becomes an oval.`?